# Delete orphaned SQL Users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, users, logins

I have a Microsoft SQL Server that had a database called SQLDATABASE. It also had a user called SQLUSER. The SQLDATABASE was deleted but not SQLUSER. SQLUSER only belonged to SQLDATABASE. I want to know all of the "Broken" users (e.g. SQLUSER) that is not part of a SQL database so that I can "clean house". I can go into every sql user and delete them by looking to see if they are attached but that seems very inefficient and something a script can help with. This is what I am asking.

The server has 200 SQL Databases but 250 SQL Users. I want to remove the extra 50 SQL Users as they aren't being used and there is no reason to have them.

I am trying to find a script to either let me find (and delete) these SQL Users or at least identify so I don't have to go into each of the SQL Users individually.

Comment: Do you mean the *login* SQLUSER was left behind? A login exists at the server level, a user exists inside a database. If you drop a database, a user can’t be left behind, but a login can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion over terminology. A user exists at the database level and is removed when you drop a database. A login exists at the server level and is mapped to a database user to get access to the database.

I'm assuming you want to find all logins that are not mapped to a database user and are therefore potentially no longer in use. The below query will achieve that:

```
CREATE TABLE ##UnusedLogins (
    [Login] NVARCHAR(255),
    [InUse] BIT
)

INSERT INTO ##UnusedLogins ([Login], [InUse])
SELECT [login].[name] AS [Login],
    0 AS [InUse]
FROM sys.server_principals [login]
WHERE [login].[name] NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE\%'
    AND [login].[name] NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY\%'
    AND [login].[name] NOT LIKE '##%'
    AND [login].[type_desc] <> 'SERVER_ROLE'
    AND [login].[name] <> 'sa'

EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'UPDATE ul
SET [InUse] = 1
FROM ##UnusedLogins ul
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals [login] ON [login].[name] = ul.[Login]
INNER JOIN [?].sys.database_principals [user] ON [user].[sid] = [login].[sid]'

SELECT * FROM ##UnusedLogins

DROP TABLE ##UnusedLogins
```

Any login in the output that has a 1 in the InUse column is mapped to a database user. Any login with a 0 is not mapped. This does not mean the login is not in use, simply that it is not mapped to any database user.

Comment: Please be aware `sp_msforeachdb` is undocumented, unsupported, and severely broken. See [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/), [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/), and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/) for better alternatives.